# CSS image sprites loading slower through CloudFront than local

Tags: css, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, sprite, amazon-cloudfront

I just changed my CSS image sprites to run from local to CloudFront and there's now a noticeable lag, even across pages and page reloads. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: What does `local` mean, in context, `localhost`?

Comment: @David Thomas, yes, localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving images from `localhost` to a server (in this case [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)) will always incur a speed penalty (relative to `localhost`, certainly). This is because even with a *great* hosting service the browser has to send an http request via the internet *to* that server, to find out whether the document's been modified since it was previously cached, or not (not modified: HTTP response `304`).

Assuming that the document doesn't need to be downloaded again/re-cached that should be the end of the image-requests for the CSS (particularly if you're using css-sprites).

If the image-sprites have to be re-downloaded because the cache has expired, or the document's changed, then obviously the browser has to download the file again, via the internet and network. And this incurs a cost due to contention on your own network/intranet, between your house and your neighbours between home and cabinet and then whatever speed your ISP provides to you.

Whereas `localhost` is the same machine, and (likely) has a response measured in the milliseconds. In contrast, accessing Amazon's CloudFront might only take a second or two, but that's still an order of magnitude (or more) greater.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason the Cache-Control headers aren't updating correctly, and I'm having a bizarre issue with the S3 browser (as in, I can't get it to load). So the browser's not doing any caching whatsoever, and I'm left unable to set any expires headers whatsoever.

Comment: And now S3 browser is back up. Must have been an outage. After setting the caching headers, the issue doesn't arise for me. But the high-level overview was definitely appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that CloudFront caches the S3 objects for 24 hours or something. So if you set Cache-Control headers on S3, but CloudFront has already cached your object before you did that, then you won't see the version of the object that has the headers set for a while.

Comment: @tfe, thanks! I guess that I *could* use their new functionality to make it expire early, but impatience is a dumb reason to do so.

Comment: Whenever you're uploading assets to a CDN configured with far-future expires headers, you should never overwrite existing assets; instead, always use a new name. Otherwise clients who have cached the original version of your assets will never find out that you updated them. This is common practice for CDNs (appending a timestamp or version number to all uploaded files).